# Why does not ECDHE-ECDSA work?

Tags: openssl, apache-http-server

I am now using this ciphersuite:

> ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA

I am using OpenSSL 1.0.1m, with Apache 2.2 on my Synology NAS. My problem is, that ECDHE-ECDSA ciphers are not in use. (tested on ssllabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sufix.cz&s=185.47.222.240)

Why does this happen? Is it just beacuse of syntax error or too old versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have an ECDSA certificate?

Comment: No, just RSA now.

Comment: That might be the problem

Comment: Is it required?

Comment: @Mat Yes. The signature algorithm in the cipher suite uses the key in your cert, so ECDSA requires a cert with an ECDSA key.